# Fixing green YUYV frame format being streamed using OpenGlView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv, image-processing

I am using a library to do RTMP streaming from an USB/UVC camera in android. The library I am using is [this one](https://github.com/alejandrorosas/android-uvc-rtmp-stream). This library works just fine for android USB cameras that are RGB. However, I am working with a thermal camera that has YUYV frame format, therefore the initial camera image is as below:

[image]

This image format is in YUV and needs some processing before the image is viewable. Therefore, I'd like to know how can I grab the frames from the camera, applying processing and then update the preview.

My problem is that, when streaming from my device, the endpoint/device receiving the stream will also view this green image, as it needs some processing, and i don't know how to correct this in android.

When connecting in Windows, I could process the image make it viewable by doing the following steps:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = frame.reshape(292, 384, 2)
    # I would remove the last 4 extra rows
    frame = frame[0:288, ...]
    # Convert image to uint16
    dt = np.dtype(('<u2', [('x', np.uint8, 2]))
    frame = frame.view(dtype=dt).astype(np.float32)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
if cv2.waiKey(1) & 0xFF = ord('q'):
    break
```

This would output a 16bit frame in greyscale

Unfortunately, i do not have considerable experience with image processing on Android, so I am not sure if I must repeat the same steps done in Python, but on android or is there any alternative/easier way to fix the frames being streamed by the OpenGlView. The stream library uses a OpenGlView to display the frames

```
<com.pedro.rtplibrary.view.OpenGlView
    android:id="@+id/openglview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:keepAspectRatio="true"
    />
```

This is the stream service that handles the camera detection

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice
import android.os.Binder
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.pedro.rtplibrary.view.OpenGlView
import com.serenegiant.usb.USBMonitor
import com.serenegiant.usb.UVCCamera
import net.ossrs.rtmp.ConnectCheckerRtmp

/**
 * Basic RTMP/RTSP service streaming implementation with camera2
 */
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class StreamService : Service() {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "RtpService"
        private const val channelId = "rtpStreamChannel"
        private const val notifyId = 123456
        private const val width = 384
        private const val height = 292

        var openGlView: OpenGlView? = null
    }

    val isStreaming: Boolean get() = endpoint != null

    private var endpoint: String? = null
    private var rtmpUSB: RtmpUSB? = null
    private var uvcCamera: UVCCamera? = null
    private var usbMonitor: USBMonitor? = null
    private val notificationManager: NotificationManager by lazy { getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.e(TAG, "RTP service create")
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelId, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        keepAliveTrick()
    }

    private fun keepAliveTrick() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("")
                .setContentText("").build()
            startForeground(1, notification)
        } else {
            startForeground(1, Notification())
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.e(TAG, "RTP service started")
        usbMonitor = USBMonitor(this, onDeviceConnectListener).apply {
            register()
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun prepareStreamRtp() {
        stopStream()
        stopPreview()

        rtmpUSB = if (openGlView == null) {
            RtmpUSB(this, connectCheckerRtmp)
        } else {
            RtmpUSB(openGlView, connectCheckerRtmp)
        }
    }

    fun startStreamRtp(endpoint: String): Boolean {
        if (rtmpUSB?.isStreaming == false) {
            this.endpoint = endpoint
            if (rtmpUSB!!.prepareVideo(width, height, 30, 4000 * 1024, false, 0, uvcCamera) && rtmpUSB!!.prepareAudio()) {
                rtmpUSB!!.startStream(uvcCamera, endpoint)
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    fun setView(view: OpenGlView) {
        openGlView = view
        rtmpUSB?.replaceView(openGlView, uvcCamera)
    }

    fun setView(context: Context) {
        openGlView = null
        rtmpUSB?.replaceView(context, uvcCamera)
    }

    fun startPreview() {
        rtmpUSB?.startPreview(uvcCamera, width, height)
    }

    private val connectCheckerRtmp = object : ConnectCheckerRtmp {
        override fun onConnectionSuccessRtmp() {
            showNotification("Stream started")
            Log.e(TAG, "RTP connection success")
        }

    private val onDeviceConnectListener = object : USBMonitor.OnDeviceConnectListener {
        override fun onAttach(device: UsbDevice?) {
            usbMonitor!!.requestPermission(device)
        }

        override fun onConnect(device: UsbDevice?, ctrlBlock: USBMonitor.UsbControlBlock?, createNew: Boolean) {
            val camera = UVCCamera()
            camera.open(ctrlBlock)
            try {
                camera.setPreviewSize(width, height, UVCCamera.FRAME_FORMAT_YUYV)
            } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                camera.destroy()
                try {
                    camera.setPreviewSize(width, height, UVCCamera.DEFAULT_PREVIEW_MODE)
                } catch (e1: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    return
                }
            }
            uvcCamera = camera
            prepareStreamRtp()
            rtmpUSB!!.startPreview(uvcCamera, width, height)
            endpoint?.let { startStreamRtp(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

The MainActivity that calls the stream service library to do the streaming:

```
import android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
import android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
import android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
import android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.ServiceConnection
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.view.SurfaceHolder
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
import com.pedro.rtplibrary.view.OpenGlView
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import dev.alejandrorosas.apptemplate.MainViewModel.ViewState
import dev.alejandrorosas.streamlib.StreamService
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main), SurfaceHolder.Callback, ServiceConnection {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    private var mService: StreamService? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("OPENCV", "OPENCV Loading Status ${OpenCVLoader.initDebug()}")

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        StreamService.openGlView = findViewById(R.id.openglview)
        startService(getServiceIntent())

        viewModel.serviceLiveEvent.observe(this) { mService?.let(it) }
        viewModel.getViewState().observe(this) { render(it) }

        findViewById<View>(R.id.settings_button).setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)) }
        findViewById<OpenGlView>(R.id.openglview).holder.addCallback(this)
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_stop_stream).setOnClickListener { viewModel.onStreamControlButtonClick() }

        requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO, CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 1)
    }

    private fun render(viewState: ViewState) {
        findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_stop_stream).setText(viewState.streamButtonText)
    }

    private fun getServiceIntent(): Intent {
        return Intent(this, StreamService::class.java).also {
            bindService(it, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }


    override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        mService?.let {
            it.setView(findViewById<OpenGlView>(R.id.openglview))
            it.startPreview()
        }
    }


    override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    }

   }
```

I implemented the native function that calls the frames from the USB camera as below in the [USBBase.Java](https://github.com/alejandrorosas/android-uvc-rtmp-stream/blob/master/libraries/streamlib/src/main/java/dev/alejandrorosas/streamlib/USBBase.java):

```
 public void startPreview(final UVCCamera uvcCamera, int width, int height) {
        Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview:mUVCCamera" + uvcCamera + " mIsPreviewing:");
        if ((uvcCamera == null)) return;
        Log.e(TAG, "handleStartPreview2 ");
        if (!isStreaming() && !onPreview && !(glInterface instanceof OffScreenGlThread)) {
            uvcCamera.setFrameCallback(mIFrameCallback, UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX);
            //uvcCamera.setValue(UVCCamera.CTRL_ZOOM_ABS, 0x8800);
            glInterface.setEncoderSize(width, height);
            glInterface.setRotation(0);
            glInterface.start();
            uvcCamera.setPreviewTexture(glInterface.getSurfaceTexture());
            uvcCamera.startPreview();
            onPreview = true;
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Streaming or preview started, ignored");
        }
    }

    // grabs the frame from the camera
    private byte[] FrameData = new byte[384 * 292 * 4];
    private final IFrameCallback mIFrameCallback = new IFrameCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFrame(final ByteBuffer frameData) {
            Log.d(TAG, "mIFrameCallback: onFrame------");
            frameData.get(FrameData, 0, frameData.capacity());
        }
    };
```

However, I don't understand if this what I got to process to have a viewable image being streamed from OpenGlView, or how can I process correctly the YUYV frame and then update my view.

I would like to know how can i fix this green image being captured by my camera

Comment: I don't intend to scrutinize this code. Can you tell me if there is a place where you specify the image format to the viewer, or if you can pass some callback function to process the image on the fly (convert the format) before display ?

Comment: YUYV is also known as YUV 4:2:2. Try the conversion COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUYV in OpenCV.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hello, thanks for the reply. In the Stream Service file, on the function onConnect, the line `camera.setPreviewSize(width, height, UVCCamera.FRAME_FORMAT_YUYV)` defines the image on the fly. FRAME_FORMAT_YUYV is one option and the other one is MJPEG which gives me black frames. The callback `uvcCamera.setFrameCallback(mIFrameCallback, UVCCamera.PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBX);` should give me the images before display, however I don't know how to pass it to opencv for processing in android

Comment: Check the prototype of the callback function, it should give you access to the frame.

Comment: The prototype: `public interface IFrameCallback {
    void onFrame(ByteBuffer var1);
}` where frameData is of type Byte buffer in . `frameData.get(FrameData, 0, frameData.capacity());`

Comment: I can't answer. This information must be in the manual of the library.